# How to map an array of data in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am having trouble on getting the latitude ,  what i've tried so far is `searchLocation.findLocationByAddress.geoCode.latitude` and i get this error

error

> LocationAdd.js:288 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'latitude')

here is my code

```
 const { data: searchLocation } = await getLocations({
    variables: {
      placeSearch: {
        address: value
      },
    },
  });
  console.log(searchLocation.findLocationByAddress)
  geoCode = {
    latitude: searchLocation.findLocationByAddress.geoCode.latitude,
    longitude: searchLocation.findLocationByAddress.geoCode.longitude,
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findLocationByAddress returns an array, I think you should call .map() or access an element with [].

Comment: how? like this 'searchLocation.map((item) => geoCode ={latitude: item.geoCode.latitude, longitude: item.geoCode.longitude})' ?  may i see your answer with code please?